# Cosmological horizon, energy and information

Tags: cosmology

If something crossed the horizon of the observable Universe, does this mean that all information about it is lost forever? If yes (or no), how this fits with the information-cannot-be-lost law?

Also, does it mean that the energy of our observable Universe is constantly decreasing? If yes, what are the consequences of that?

Answer (score -1):

The horizon of the observable universe can be thought as a type of cosmic event horizon. Therefore the same paradox applies to it like in the case of [black holes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_information_paradox).